# View a tweet in the context of a user's feed

Tags: twitter

Recently I came across a tweet from around a year ago and wanted to know what that user was tweeting before and after that particular tweet. I was surprised to find that there doesn't seem to be any good way to do this, the date filtering on the advanced search doesn't seem to work at all, in fact the advanced search seems pretty broken in general.

I looked online but couldn't really find anything about this, is it really true that the only way to do this is manually scrolling? As far as I can tell there's no indication the search in the public API would be any more powerful than the website's advanced search, is this not the case?

To summarise, is there any way to navigate to a certain point in the past in a person's Twitter feed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the Twitter web client by typing the following search query in the search field:

```
from:{username} since:{YYYY}-{mm}-{mm} until:{YYYY}-{mm}-{mm}
```

Where **`{yyyy}`** = 4 digit year, **`{mm}`** = 2 digit month & **`{dd}`** = 2 digit day.

Your search query should look like this:

```
from:jack since:2016-10-01 until:2016-10-10
```

This query will fetch all the tweets made by @jack between Oct. 1, 2016 and Oct. 10 2016.